# How to tell Nest ElasticSearch to only use InterfaceProperties

Tags: c#, interface, elasticsearch, nest

We are looking into ElasticSearch (Nest) but run into a problem.
In our application we only want to use interfaces for our objects. In these interfaces I would like to be able to set which properties to index and which not.

```
public interface ISomething {
    string Name {get;set;}
    int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Something: ISomething {
  public string Name { get;set; }
  public int Id {get;set;}
  // This property should not be visible
  public string VerySecretCode {get;set}
}
```

When we index a Interface  by creating a new ElasticClient() ALL the properties from the object are put into the json. Is it posible to tell ElasticClient that we only want the properties exposed by the interface to show up?

Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with adding a own converter to the settings:
    public class MyConverter : ElasticContractResolver
    {

```
    public MyConverter(IConnectionSettingsValues connectionSettings)
        : base(connectionSettings)
    {
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.Assembly.FullName.Contains("MyDefinition") && objectType.IsInterface)
        {
            var name = objectType.Name;
            //Check if name starts with an 'I' and the second char is a UpperCase aswell to be sure the given Type.Name is a interface.
            if (name.StartsWith("I") && char.IsUpper(name[1]))
            {
                //Remove the I from the name
                name = name.Substring(1);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(<MyAssembly>);
                Type t = assembly.GetType("MyNamespace" + name);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    objectType = t;
                }

            }
        }

        var baseReturn = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        return baseReturn;
    }

}
```

After that our own object is created instead of trying to instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is a best practice to have separate data models from domain models.  I recommend that you create a new class/interface ISomethingForES.  You can then use Automapper or something similar to map the fields for you.  The advantage is that then you can annotate SomethingForES with with ES specific attributes that do not belong in your domain model.  Here is an example:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "type123")]
public class SomethingForES: ISomethingForES {
  public string Name { get;set; }
  public int Id {get;set;}
}
```